# ipython qt console: change the default working directory

Tags: python, qt, ipython

I installed WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7 and use Ipython QT console.
Its defalult working directory is "WinPython-32bit-3.4.3.7\notebooks" by the magic command "%pwd".

I would like to change the default directory to "C:\workspace",for example.

I read the configuration files in "settings\.ipython\profile_default\ipython_config.py and ipython_kernel_config.py".
But I don't find any good solution.

Please tell me whatever trick I can change the default directory!

UPDATE: I understand the way I change the default directory to any directory I like with opening notebook but when applying to qt console, it failed.
In case of Qt Console, isn't it thought to be necessary to change the default directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I correctly remember

```
ipython --notebook-dir=<working/dir>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry again..[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Invalid argument: '--notebook-dir=c:\workspace\'

Comment: It works when starting notebook but it doesn't work when starting qtconsole. I cannot find the command of qtconsole...

Comment: Ok, the first variant what come on my mind is, to not use noteboook-dir at all but simply switch to desired dir by cd and then start ipython qtconsole from comandline there (of course all can be wrapped to bat file). Or another possibility is to use qtconsole as a terminal. I mean to split start to ipython kernel and ipython qconsole. Im sorry i dont have currently ipython on win and dont remember correct syntax but i think it can be found here: (https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/qtconsole.html)

Comment: Special thanks to your answer. But in my environment, I cannot get path to the folder where ipython qtconsole exists. Of course, I tried to use qtconsole as a terminal and it worked. I don't know how to go to the any directory by a command. It is ok even if I use a cheat like a shortcut link.Special thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `os` module in python with the following commands.

- To get the current working directory use this - `os.getcwd()`
- To set a new working directory use this - `os.chdir(<absolute path>)`

Hope this helps.